# Whether my apps delete after software update in Sony Xperia tipo in Sony Service centre?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My Android deivce is a **Sony Xperia Tipo**.

Recently, I got my Tipo's `System Software` **Updated** from **Sony Service Centre**.

I also found that **sans-update**, some (or all) of my installed Apps as **absent/uninstalled**.

Please help me regarding this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not really sure what your question is here, could you perhaps reword it to help us understand?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to send it in for service, they might decide to make a "clean install". In that case, your apps and data are of course gone. With a "normal update", apps and data might survive.

But it's never a bad idea to make a [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) (see also our [backup tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for hints, as well as the links to further information contained there – especially [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575)). This way, even if some or all apps don't survive the update, you can still restore them from your backup.